# How can K8S api-servers access to ETCD cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

Let's assume that api-server and etcd cluster were deployed in pod using kubeadm.
Service and ingress are not created for ETCD in `kube-system` namespace.
Then, how can K8S api-servers access to ETCD cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

etcd(pod or daemon) using server ip. so apiserver can connect with etcd without any service. you can check these options in etcd.yaml
e.g
hostNetwork: true
--advertise-client-urls=https://[server-ip]:2379